# How do I create UIViewController using Xib-file?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

Sorry if this question has already been answered but I can't find an answer.

I'm creating an app in which I have an UITableViewController and when the accessorybutton in the right side of a cell is selected a new instance of a UIViewController should be created containing the interface found in a .xib-file. The new UIViewController will then be pushed on to the stack and displayed.
My question is how do I create the new UIViewController from an existing .xib-file?

This is what I have tried so far:
In Xcode: File -> New File -> Cocoa Touch Class -> UIViewController subClass.
Checkbox "UITableViewController subclass" unchecked.
Checkbox "With XIB for user interface" checked.

This creates a .m, a .h and a .xib file. I created a user interface in the "view" in the .xib-file. Selecting "File's owner" in interface builder shows the newly created UIViewController in "Class Identity".

Some code:

In DetailViewController.m (the new UIViewController):

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
     return self;
}
```

In SubViewController.m (the old UITableViewController):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
     //Exception thrown at line below
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
}
```

Forgot to mention that the .xib-file's name is "DetailViewController.xib".

The code compiles fine but when I run it in the simulator and press an accessorybutton it terminates due to uncaught exception.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In Xcode, set a breakpoint for `objc_exception_thrown` so GDB will halt when the exception is being thrown, so you can see the stack-trace and some insight information you'll probably need.

Comment: Also, in the console you should get a log about the uncaught exception. Add that to your question, as it usually provides an important clue about what went wrong.

Comment: Ok, I'm new to Xcode so I will look into that. But it should work this way? I'm not way off? The initWithNibName method and all that seems to be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in the new view I was trying to display. In the .xib-file I had inserted a MKMapView and when I removed this it all works perfectly.

Thanks again for helping me debug!

Comment: and btw if you want an MKMapView you should use the MapKit framework

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to cast this:

```
DetailViewController
*detailViewController = (DetailViewController*)[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Are you getting a compiler warning if you don't?