# How to make a roundrect button overlay?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have the overlay below which appears every time my camera preview screen loads. I'd like to create a round rect button on the overlay programmatically named "Finished". How do I do so?

```
- (UIView*)CommomOverlay {

    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,430)];
    UIImageView *FrameImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,430)];

    [FrameImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newGraphicOverlay.png"]];
    FrameImg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [view addSubview:FrameImg];

    return view;
}
```

Also, what would I add in my `finishButtonPressed` method to bring up a view of a nib named `testviewcontroller`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210408/iphone-dev-create-uibutton-manually  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072888/how-do-i-create-uiviewcontroller-using-xib-file

Comment: You are asking two completely unrelated questions here, which does not really work in this format. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) You could end up with an answer that is both correct and incorrect. Split them up into two separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Here's a blue button added to the center of your view:

```
UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,430)];
UIImageView *FrameImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,430)];

[FrameImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newGraphicOverlay.png"]];
FrameImg.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[view addSubview:FrameImg];

UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 50)];
button.center = view.center;
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
button.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
button.titleLabel.text = @"Finished";

[view addSubview:button];
```

2.) You should:

- Attach a segue in your storyboard
- Name the segue identifier
- Call performSegueWithIdentifier
- (Be sure to implement prepareForSegue, if you want extra work to be done before the segue)